# Show that $\phi(G^{(k)})=(G/N)^{(k)}$ where $G^{(k)}=[G^{(k-1)},G^{(k-1)}]$ is the commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $N \unlhd G$ and $\phi:G\rightarrow G/N$ be canonical homomorphism, then $\phi(G^{(k)})=(G/N)^{(k)}$.

So far I have this:

Let $[x,y] \in G^{(k)}$ be a generator of $G^{(k)}$. Then $\phi([x,y]) = [x,y]N \in (G/N)^{(k)}$. Hence $\phi(G^{(k)}) \subset (G/N)^{(k)}$.

But since $\phi$ is a surjection, we have $|\phi(G^{(k)})| \geq |(G/N)^{(k)}|$, hence equality.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention that you have used the induction hypothesis that $\phi(G^{(k-1)})=(G/N)^{(k-1)}$ to claim that $[x,y]N\in(G/N)^{(k)}$.

For surjectivity, let $xN,yN\in (G/N)^{(k-1)}$, then by induction hypothesis there exists $x^\prime,y^\prime\in G^{(k-1)}$ such that $\phi(x^\prime)=xN$ and $\phi(y^\prime)=yN$, so $\phi([x^\prime,y^\prime])=[xN,yN]$ and $[x^\prime,y^\prime]\in G^{(k)}$.